# Windows, duplicate network connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, dns

I want to duplicate current connected wired network connection in `Windows 10` and then change its `DNS` so I can switch between them when I need. Although I can change `DNS` of connection and revert that; but I think duplicating will save some time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of duplicating the connection (I don't think it's possible), you can create two batch files for setting DNS (so you can switch between them clicking on the files).

The command is:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="YOUR INTERFACE NAME" static DNS_SERVER
```

For example:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Wi-Fi" static 8.8.8.8
```